# Resized with iPartition but MacOS still reports old partition size

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I resized an external drive partition from 800 to 900 GB with iPartition but MacOS still reports old size.
Did unmount drives, did restart, but still.
MacOS 10.12.6
iPartition 3.6.2 (216)

[image]

[image]

### Update:

`diskutil list` command does report correctly the ~900GB the partition has, but finder keeps reporting ~800GB

[image]

Comment: Your issue here might be finding anyone who still has iPartition. The developers ceased production after Mojave, as they couldn't support APFS, so users are going to be few & far between now. Ordinarily it would be a good question to ask the developers, but as they've closed the operation down, that's no longer going to be possible. I do wish you luck, though :) Could you edit & add to your question the results of the following commands in Terminal - `diskutil list` & `diskutil cs list` [one may come up empty]

Comment: Yeah, that's why I finally have a valid license :).
Thanks, I updated the question. `diskutil` actually reports ~900GB, I'd be fine with finder reporting less capacity if the partition will allow the full capacity to be used. Hope that's the case.